# Is it possible to compare date ("Y-m-d H:i:s") with time() inside mysqli_query?

Tags: php, sql

I would like to select from database 10 most popular posts posted in last 24 hours based on likes.
In database for each post I stored time when the post was posted using date("Y-m-d H:i:s") in column post_date.

I need something like this:

```
$most_popular = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE (time() - post_date) < 86400 ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 10");
```

Comment: I'd advise you to avoid complex queries instead you should preprocess the date with PHP. MySQL is likely to become the [bottleneck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottleneck) before your web server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM posts 
WHERE post_date > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
ORDER BY likes DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just compare the `post_date` with 24 hours before:

```
$last_24_hours = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("-24 Hours"));
$query = sprintf("SELECT * 
                    FROM posts 
                   WHERE post_date > '%s'
                ORDER BY likes DESC
                   LIMIT 10", $last_24_hours);
$most_popular = mysqli_query($mysqli_connect, $query);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM posts
WHERE post_date >= (now() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)
ORDER BY ...
etc...
```

Comment: that will not get last 24 hours will it? post_date - interval 1 day will get last 24 hours of the post date not current date

Answer (score 0):

Your question is: "Is it possible to compare date (“Y-m-d H:i:s”) with time() inside mysqli_query?"

The answer is yes:

```
SELECT TIME('2003-12-31 01:02:03'); // returns '01:02:03'
```

NOTE: This CAN'T handle many dates, if that's your question.

Comment: how would you get records for last 24 hours using your method ?

Comment: This method is from the mysql documentation. And that depends on how the question is translated, he can't compare dates, but that is what one gets with such an unclear question.

Comment: then you should've asked him in the comments first to find out what he wants. i think he meant time() as PHP time() function that returns the current time in timestamp